# golang validate struct with tags

Tags: go

I'm a Nestjs developer & have started to learn golang recently. What I need to ask is validation with tags. In Nestjs, validation is performed with custom class decorators. It's very easy to get a grasp. They're also type safe.
I got below sample struct from golang documentation;

```golang
type User struct {
    FirstName      string `validate:"requiredx"`
    LastName       string `validatex:"required"`
    Age            uint8  `validate:"gte=0,lte=130"`
    Email          string `validate:"required,email"`
    Gender         string `validate:"oneof=male female prefer_not_to"`
    FavouriteColor string `validate:"iscolor"` // alias for 'hexcolor|rgb|rgba|hsl|hsla'

}
```

as you see, I distorted both tags for **FirstName** & **LastName** But there's no build time warning. Is it possible to make this validation tags type safe? Otherwise it may create very undesired results in run time.
Or am I missing sth?

Comment: in go programming language the struct tags are essentially just strings, and their interpretation is left up to the code that uses them. Therefore, there's no built-in mechanism for making struct tags type safe, and you won't get a build-time warning if you use an incorrect or misspelled tag.

Comment: these validation tags can have significant impact on the business logic. It's very dissappointing about Golang that it's just using dummy strings while TpeScript addresses these things with class decorators much more elegantly & reliably

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make this validation tags type safe?

No.

Answer (score 0):

The [library](https://github.com/go-playground/validator) you're talking about, can not have all validations existed. But that allows you to implement your custom business-logic validations.
You can look at [this example](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/master/_examples/custom-validation/main.go).